# Dynamically include JS and CSS links in one file

Tags: google-apps-script

What is the expected output for

```
//function in external file  
function CommonCss(){ var cssfilename = ['googledrive.com/host/xxxx/style1.css','googledrive.com/host/xxxx/style2.css'];
    for (var i = 0; i < cssfilename.length; i++) {
        var headHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML;
 headHTML += '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="' + cssfilename[i] + '">';
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML = headHTML;
    }
}
```

Linking the CSS files works on a normal HTML page on a local server (WAMP), but the same code does not work in Google Apps Script.

Project key : M5ahR5WvtWTu1_Wlkofz5DfzFem3cSiUf

App Link    : http://goo.gl/2zExIB

Source Code : http://goo.gl/PNlKiS

We described our requirements in app link.

Could you suggest the best way to append multiple JS and CSS files from one external JS function so that we can add that one line in multiple forms and projects.

Comment: Please don't shout in your question title.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to dynamically add CSS files when using the HtmlService's EMULATED sandboxing mode:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#adding_css_dynamically

If you switch to using NATIVE mode it should work correctly.